# simplex - algebraic intuition behind the basis of the canoncial form

Tags: algorithm, linear-algebra, mathematical-optimization, linear-programming, simplex

I'm trying to understand the simplex iteration of a problem with `n` variables and `m` technological constraints by following this [text](https://www2.isye.gatech.edu/%7Espyros/LP/node23.html). I understand well the geometric interpretation of the iteration - moving between adjacent vertices.

However, I fail to understand the algebraic intuition. Now we're `pivoting` between adjacent `basic feasible solutions` = `bfs` to the standard form of `AX + IS = b`, `X,S >= 0` :

1. Why is it that the bfs must have `n` variables equal to 0?
2. Why should the rest of the variables form a `basis`? Isn't a basis a set of linearly independent vectors spanning a sub-space? What are we spanning here, we're just looking for a vertex, aren't we?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. The BFS should correctly have `n-m` non-basic variables set to `0`. Some of the `m` basic variables may themselves be `0` but that is a degenerate solution.
2. The basis is indeed the minimal set of linearly independent variables that span vector `b`. Note that `b` is an `m-vector`. So, `m` of the vectors corresponding to the variables can form a `BFS`. The total number of variables is `n`. The number of bases is therefore exponential `n Choose m`.

Pivoting or moving from one vertex to another is nothing but substituting one of the non-basic variables (the associated column vector) into the basis and removing a pre-existing variable out of the basis. Thus, the basis will always have `m` (column) vectors.

At any one point in time, given a partition of A into basic and nonbasic variables, such as `A = [B|N]`, then `Bx = b` and hence the `x` variables are the coefficients of the span of `B` that gives `b`.

It is a fundamental result of linear programming that every vertex of a bounded linearly constrained LP's feasible polyhedron corresponds to basic solution and vice versa. Reference: https://press.princeton.edu/titles/413.html